# How can i keep the same session using subprocess in Pytest script

Tags: python, postgresql, subprocess, pytest

I am writing a Pytest where I am creating temp tables in memory in db using a fixture and scoping the fixture to sesssion.

```
@fixture(scope='session')
def tmp_dim_sponsor(get_redshift_connection):
    sql = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mock_tmp_dim_sponsor;
        CREATE TEMP TABLE mock_tmp_dim_sponsor (LIKE 
tmp.tmp_dim_sponsor);"""
    execute_sql_no_return(sql, get_redshift_connection, False)
    print("mock_tmp_dim_sponsor Created")
```

I then have another fixture which calls a bash script using subprocess. This bash scripts needs to reference these temp tables that were created earlier using the fixture. The bash scripts makes a new connection to db and then executes the sql which has reference to temp tables created earlier.

```
@fixture(scope='session')
def dim_sponsor_transformation_1(get_redshift_connection):
    copy2('/dim_sponsor_transformation_test.sh', 
'/tmp_dim_sponsor_transformation.sh')
    with open("tmp_dim_sponsor_transformation.sh", "r+") as file1:
        with open("mock_dim_sponsor_transformation.sh", "w") as file2:
            for line in file1:
                new = re.sub(r'\$\{\w*SCHEMA\}\.', "mock_", line)
                new1 = re.sub(r'check_status \$\?.*', "", new)
                new2 = re.sub(r'>> \$LOGDIR.*', "", new1)
                new3 = re.sub(r'log .*"', "", new2)
                new4 = re.sub(r'SCRIPTDIR="\$HOME/scripts"', 
'SCRIPTDIR="/Users/abc/src/main/scripts"', new3)
                file2.write(new4)
            file.close(file1)
            file.close(file2)
            print(file2)
    os.chmod('mock_dim_sponsor_transformation.sh', 0o777)
    print("Changed the permission")
    print("Starting to Run the Transformation")
    t = 
subprocess.check_output(["./mock_dim_sponsor_transformation.sh", 
"qa"])
    print(t)
    print("Completed Transformation")
```

The bash script (mock_dim_sponsor_transformation.sh) makes a new connection to db and then executes the sql.

```
SCRIPTDIR="/User/xxx/xxx/src/main/scripts"
source $SCRIPTDIR/utils/get_environment.sh $1
export PGPASSWORD=$RSDBPASSWORD

PAST_DAY=$(date -d "yesterday" +"%Y-%m-%d")
PAST_DAY_VALUE="'"${PAST_DAY}"'"

psql -h $RSDBHOST -p $RSDBHOSTPORT -U $RSDBOWNER -d $RSDBNAME -c \
"
TRUNCATE mock_tmp_dim_sponsor;
" 

psql -h $RSDBHOST -p $RSDBHOSTPORT -U $RSDBOWNER -d $RSDBNAME -c \
"
INSERT INTO     mock_tmp_dim_sponsor
            (
            sponsor_legacy_id,
            sponsor_id,
            name,
            plan_type,
            default_segment_id,
            created_date,
            updated_date,
            is_genesis,
            sponsor_display_name,
             ...
```

However it is not able to find those temp tables which i guess makes sense b/c 
1. Since the bash script is making a new connection to db, it will not find temp tables since temp tables are in memory of that session.
2. Does subprocess creates a new session when calling another script?

Any suggestions on how can i be able to reference the the temp tables created in fixture in the bash script? 
Also, is there a way i can pass the db connection object in subprocess call so that mock_dim_sponsor_transformation.sh does not make a new connection?

I am fairly new to Pytest and still learning. Any suggestions or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Does subprocess creates a new session when calling another script?

A new session is created not by the `subprocess.check_output()` but by `psql` called in the bash script.

> Any suggestions on how can i be able to reference the the temp tables created in fixture in the bash script?

Temporary tables are only available for the same connection/transaction, so the only way to use them is to run SQL commands inside the main process without any subprocesses (shell scripts).

Or make these tables permanent and drop them yourself after the shell script.

> Also, is there a way i can pass the db connection object in subprocess?

No, there is no way.